# error message in data from storm radar

Tags: php

I have my own thunderstorm radar. The lightning detection is taken from an external server. The script works fine, but there is sometimes a error in this data. The following error shows that:

> *PHP fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C: \inetpub\ftp\blitzorgtung\main.php on line 47*

This is the php script from main.php:

```
<?php
$strikes1 = null;
$strikes2 = null;
$strikes3 = null;
$strikes4 = null;
$strikes5 = null;
$strikes6 = null;

//
// strikes and stations path
//
$strikes_dir= 'http://' . $username . ':' . $password . '@data.blitzortung.org/Data_' . $region . '/Protected/Strikes/';
$stations_file= 'http://' . $username . ':' . $password . '@data.blitzortung.org/Data_' . $region . '/Protected/stations.json.gz';

//
// times
//
$end_time= time();

//
// renew local data file
//
if (filemtime($local_strikes_file) < $end_time-60) {

  touch ($local_strikes_file);

  $l_time= $end_time-$time_span;
  $l_file= @fopen($local_strikes_file, 'r');
  $t_file= @fopen($tmp_strikes_file, 'w');
  while ($line= fgets ($l_file)) {
    $strike= json_decode($line);
    $strike->time/= 1000000000;
    if ($strike->time >= $end_time-$time_span) {
      fwrite ($t_file, $line);
      $l_time= $strike->time;
    }
  }
  fclose ($l_file);
  fclose ($t_file);
  rename ($tmp_strikes_file,$local_strikes_file);

  $run_time= $l_time;
  $l_file= @fopen($local_strikes_file, 'a');
  while ($run_time < $end_time+600) {
    $filename= $strikes_dir . gmdate("Y/m/d/H/",$run_time) . $run_time/600%6 . '0.json';
    if ($file= @fopen($filename, 'r')) {
      while ($line= fgets ($file)) {
        $json= json_decode($line);
        $json->time/= 1000000000;
        if ($json->time >= $l_time) {
          fwrite ($l_file, $line);
        }
      }
      fclose ($file);
    }
    else {
      $gzfilename= $strikes_dir . gmdate("Y/m/d/H/",$run_time) . $run_time/600%6 . '0.json.gz';
      if ($file= @gzopen($filename, 'r')) {
        while ($line= gzgets ($file)) {
          $json= json_decode($line);
          $json->time/= 1000000000;
          if ($json->time >= $l_time) {
            fwrite ($l_file, $line);
          }
        }
        gzclose ($file);
      }
    }
    $run_time+= 600;
  }
  fclose ($l_file);
}

//
// copy image
//
$img= imagecreatefrompng($map);
$img_width= imagesx($img);
$img_hight= imagesy($img);

//
// colors
//
$black       = imagecolorallocate($img,   0,   0,   0);

$white       = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$yellow      = imagecolorallocate($img, 100, 255, 255);
$orange      = imagecolorallocate($img, 0,   200, 255);
$red_light   = imagecolorallocate($img, 0,   125, 255);
$red         = imagecolorallocate($img, 0,   50,  255);
$red_dark    = imagecolorallocate($img, 0,   0,   200);

$white_10    = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 20);
$yellow_10   = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255,   0, 20);
$orange_10   = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 170,   0, 20);
$red_light_10= imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255,  85,   0, 20);
$red_10      = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255,   0,   0, 20);
$red_dark_10 = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 191,   0,   0, 20);

$gray        = imagecolorallocate($img, 143, 143, 143);
$black_95 = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 95);

$city_col    = imagecolorallocate($img,  63,  63,  63);

$active_col  = imagecolorallocate($img,  63, 191,  63);
$idle_col    = imagecolorallocate($img, 191, 191,  63);
$fault_col   = imagecolorallocate($img, 191,  63,  63);
$inactive_col= imagecolorallocate($img, 159, 159, 159);

//
// mercator projection
//
function mercator_proj ($lat)
{
  $lat= (float)$lat;
  return(log(tan(pi()/4.0+$lat/2.0)));
}

//
// draw strikes
//
$strikes= 0;
$str_cnt= array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$file= @fopen($local_strikes_file, 'r');
while ($line= fgets ($file)) {
  $strike= json_decode($line);
  $strike->time/=1000000000;
  if (($end_time-$time_span < $strike->time)&&($strike->time <= $end_time)&&
      ($west <= rad($strike->lon))&&(rad($strike->lon) <= $east)&&
      ($north >= rad($strike->lat))&&(rad($strike->lat) >= $south)) {

    $x= (int)(($img_width)*(rad($strike->lon)-$west)/($east-$west));
    $y= (int)($img_width*(mercator_proj($north)-mercator_proj(rad($strike->lat)))/($east-$west));

    if ($end_time-$strike->time < $time_span/6) {
      $str_cnt[0]++;
      $col= $white;
    }
    else if ($end_time-$strike->time < 2*$time_span/6) {
      $str_cnt[1]++;
      $col= $yellow;
    }
    else if ($end_time-$strike->time < 3*$time_span/6) {
      $str_cnt[2]++;
      $col= $orange;
    }
    else if ($end_time-$strike->time < 4*$time_span/6) {
      $str_cnt[3]++;
      $col= $red_light;
    }
    else if ($end_time-$strike->time < 5*$time_span/6) {
      $str_cnt[4]++;
      $col= $red;
    }
    else {
      $str_cnt[5]++;
      $col= $red_dark;
    }
//
// star
//
    imageline ($img, $x-3, $y+0, $x+3, $y+0, $col);
    imageline ($img, $x+0, $y-3, $x+0, $y+3, $col);
    imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x-1, $y-1, $x+1, $y-1, $x+1, $y+1, $x-1, $y+1), 4, $col);
//
// square
//
//    imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x-2, $y-2, $x+2, $y-2, $x+2, $y+2, $x-2, $y+2), 4, $col);

//
// ball
//
//    imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x-1, $y-2, $x+1, $y-2, $x+2, $y-1, $x+2, $y+1, $x+1, $y+2, $x-1, $y+2, $x-2, $y+1, $x-2, $y-1), 8, $col);

//
// flash
//
//    imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y-10, $x+7, $y-10, $x+2, $y-3, $x+7, $y-3, $x-6, $y+10, $x-1, $y, $x-4, $y), 7, $col);
//    imagepolygon       ($img, array ($x, $y-10, $x+7, $y-10, $x+2, $y-3, $x+7, $y-3, $x-6, $y+10, $x-1, $y, $x-4, $y), 7, $black);

    $strikes++;
  }
}
fclose ($file);

//
// draw stations
/*
$stations= 0;
if (($gzfile= gzopen($stations_file, 'r')) != false) {
  while ($line = gzgets($gzfile)) {
    $station= json_decode($line);
    if ($station->station > 0) {

      if (($west <= rad($station->longitude))&&(rad($station->longitude) <= $east)&&
          ($north >= rad($station->latitude))&&(rad($station->latitude) >= $south)) {

        $x= (int)(($img_width)*(rad($station->longitude)-$west)/($east-$west));
        $y= (int)($img_width*(mercator_proj($north)-mercator_proj(rad($station->latitude)))/($east-$west));

        $col= $fault_col;
        if ($station->controller_status == "10") {
          $col= $inactive_col;
        }
        if ($station->controller_status == "20") {
          $col= $idle_col;
        }
        if ($station->controller_status == "30") {
          $col= $active_col;
        }

        imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x-3, $y-3, $x+3, $y-3, $x+3, $y+3, $x-3, $y+3), 4, $col);
        imagepolygon ($img, array ($x-3, $y-3, $x+3, $y-3, $x+3, $y+3, $x-3, $y+3), 4, $black);
        imageline    ($img, $x-1, $y, $x+1, $y, $black);
        imageline    ($img, $x, $y-1, $x, $y+1, $black);
        imagestring ($img, 2, $x+5, $y-15, $station->city, $white);

        $stations++;
      }
    }
  }
  gzclose($gzfile);
}
*/
//
// draw cities
/*
foreach ($cities_array as $city_line ) {
  $lat= strtok($city_line,';')*pi()/180.0;
  $lon= strtok(';')*pi()/180.0;
  $city = strtok(';');
  if (($lon >= $west)&&($lon <= $east)&&($lat <= $north)&&($lat >= $south)) {

    $x= (int)(($img_width)*($lon-$west)/($east-$west));
    $y= (int)($img_width*(mercator_proj($north)-mercator_proj($lat))/($east-$west));

    imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x-2, $y-2, $x-2, $y+2, $x+2, $y+2, $x+2, $y-2), 4, $city_col);
    imagepolygon ($img, array ($x-2, $y-2, $x-2, $y+2, $x+2, $y+2, $x+2, $y-2), 4, $gray);
    imagestring ($img, 2, $x+5, $y-15, $city, $city_col);
  }
}
*/
//
// draw function
//
function draw_text ($img, $font, $x, $y, $text, $font_col, $bg_col)
{
  if ($x < 0) {
    $x+= imagesx($img)-strlen($text)*7;
  }
  if ($y < 0) {
    $y+= imagesy($img)-13;
  }
  imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+12, $x+strlen($text)*7, $y+12, $x+strlen($text)*7, $y), 4, $bg_col);
  imagestring ($img, $font, $x, $y, $text, $font_col);
}

//
// draw header lines
//
draw_text ($img, 3, 0, 0, "Blitzortung.org contributors, AOT", $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, -1, 0, date('Y-m-d T H:i:s',$end_time-$time_span), $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, -1, 26, sprintf ("Strikes:%5d",$strikes), $white, $black_95);

//
// draw legend
//
draw_text ($img, 3, 8, 24, sprintf ("  %3d Minutes",intval(1*$time_span/6/60)), $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, 8, 37, sprintf ("  %3d",intval(2*$time_span/6/60)), $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, 8, 50, sprintf ("  %3d",intval(3*$time_span/6/60)), $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, 8, 63, sprintf ("  %3d",intval(4*$time_span/6/60)), $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, 8, 76, sprintf ("  %3d",intval(5*$time_span/6/60)), $white, $black_95);
draw_text ($img, 3, 8, 89, sprintf ("  %3d",intval(6*$time_span/6/60)), $white, $black_95);

$x= 10;
$y= 28;
imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $white);
imagepolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $gray);
$y+= 13;
imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $yellow);
imagepolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $gray);
$y+= 13;
imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $orange);
imagepolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $gray);
$y+= 13;
imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $red_light);
imagepolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $gray);
$y+= 13;
imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $red);
imagepolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $gray);
$y+= 13;
imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $red_dark);
imagepolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y+5, $x+5, $y+5, $x+5, $y), 4, $gray);

//
// draw statistics
//
function draw_statistic ($img, $font, $x, $y, $text, $width, $font_col, $bg_col)
{
  if ($x < 0) {
    $x+= imagesx($img);
  }
  if ($y < 0) {
    $y+= imagesy($img);
  }
  imagefilledpolygon ($img, array ($x, $y, $x, $y-$width, $x+12, $y-$width, $x+12, $y), 4, $bg_col);
  imagestringup ($img, $font, $x, $y-$width+strlen($text)*8, $text, $font_col);
}

$x= 3;
$y= imagesy($img)-4;
imageline ($img, $x, $y, $x, $y-58, $white);
imageline ($img, $x, $y, $x+81, $y, $white);
$x++;
$y--;

if (($strikes1 < $strikes2)||
    ($strikes1 < $strikes3)||
    ($strikes1 < $strikes4)||
    ($strikes1 < $strikes5)||
    ($strikes1 < $strikes6)) {
  $strikes1= "";
}
if (($strikes2 < $strikes3)||
    ($strikes2 < $strikes4)||
    ($strikes2 < $strikes5)||
    ($strikes2 < $strikes6)) {
  $strikes2= "";
}
if (($strikes3 < $strikes4)||
    ($strikes3 < $strikes5)||
    ($strikes3 < $strikes6)) {
  $strikes3= "";
}
if (($strikes4 < $strikes5)||
    ($strikes4 < $strikes6)) {
  $strikes4= "";
}
if (($strikes5 < $strikes6)) {
  $strikes4= "";
}

$max= 0;
for ($i= 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
  if ($str_cnt[$i] > $max) {
    $max= $str_cnt[$i];
  }
}

$str_cnt_disp= array ("", "", "", "", "", "");
for ($i= 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
  if ($str_cnt[$i] == $max) {
    $str_cnt_disp[$i]= $max;
  }
}

if( $max > 0) {
  draw_statistic ($img, 3, $x, $y, $str_cnt_disp[5],  55*$str_cnt[5]/$max, $white, $red_dark);
  $x+=13;
  draw_statistic ($img, 3, $x, $y, $str_cnt_disp[4],  55*$str_cnt[4]/$max, $white, $red);
  $x+=13;
  draw_statistic ($img, 3, $x, $y, $str_cnt_disp[3],  55*$str_cnt[3]/$max, $white, $red_light);
  $x+=13;
  draw_statistic ($img, 3, $x, $y, $str_cnt_disp[2],  55*$str_cnt[2]/$max, $white, $orange);
  $x+=13;
  draw_statistic ($img, 3, $x, $y, $str_cnt_disp[1],  55*$str_cnt[1]/$max, $black, $yellow);
  $x+=13;
  draw_statistic ($img, 3, $x, $y, $str_cnt_disp[0],  55*$str_cnt[0]/$max, $black, $white);
}

//
// output image
//
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);

//
// free memory
//
imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is `$local_strikes_file`?

Comment: There are adjustments you can make in php.ini to bump up the script execution time, it seems like (as Alex Howansky said) whatever you're trying to process larger/longer than the configuration is set for.

Comment: 1. Stop using `@` to suppress error messages. 2. Actually check the return value of the functions instead of just blundering on past potential error states. 3. Fix the errors that you're now no longer ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the run time limit with set_time_limit(0). Add this at the beginning of the file.

Most likely 30 seconds is not long enough to process some of the input files that are processed by this script.

Comment: Setting any time limits / execution time to have no upper bounds (infinite) can lead to some nasty results. It's a good idea to have SOME limitation on the length / size of processes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have the limit chanced and the error is gone :)